# How to execute update hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

How to run the  this query

```
update User user 
set user.status = 1 
where user.status = 0 
  and user.uiid = 12 or user.uiid =13 or user.uiid =14 or user.uiid =15
```

getHibernateTemplate()

I mean `getHibernateTemplate(). my query...

Please give me the example ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The object oriented way:

```
foreach(int id in ids)
{
  User user = session.get<User>(id);
  user.status = 1;
}
```

The hql way:

```
session
  .createQuery("update User set status = :status where id in (:ids)");
  .setInt("status", status)
  .setParameterList("ids", ids)
  .executeUpdate();
```

It depends on what you are doing in the whole transaction to say which way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use hibernateTemplate.find(HqlQuery)

See more varitions to find() method http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html